# Black & white manga involving a magic sword-wielding general (possibly ex-general) and a princess

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read a manga a while back. From what I remember the main character always wears the same clothes (picture below, excuse the bad quality since I drew it myself). There was a joke that lasted a page or so that when the protagonist opened his wardrobe/closet, there were a lot of pairs of the same clothes. Pretty sure it was a sleeveless shirt/jacket, although it might not be sleeveless, it was definitely black.

[image]

The main character is or was a general, can't quite remember. He had a either a demon sword or a very infamous one. The protagonist had a castle and a small army. He also met this princess when he wasn't very well known yet (the princess was a lot younger than when the main story takes place). They don't recognise each other until they traveled together quite a bit. I most likely read it on isekaiscan.com (the manga wasn't an isekai), since that's the only site I used when I read it. I remember finding it on kissmanga accidentally as well, but it was still quite a while ago.  Also, it was a japanese monochrome comic just to be specific.

To describe characters in a few sentences, and in a bit more detail:

- The protagonist - He was a general that got pretty infamous due to how many wars he won. He met a princess while he was still a general, and then later met her when he became a mercenary (or a noble/lord, can't exactly remember). He owned a castle/fortress and a small army. After meeting the princess they traveled together for a while before recognising eachother. He had black hair and, if I remember correctly, he also had black eyes. He also had a well known sword, because it was a demon sword (might not specifically be a demon sword, but one that sucks someone's life/decreases the wielder's lifespan).
- The princess - Can't remember much about her except that she liked the protagonist and also had bright hair (can't tell exactly, since it's in black and white).

Comment: Can you visit [this list of prompts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [edit] in any more details that elicits? If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: Good work! That gives us more to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be [Rain](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=38313)

Rain is a general black hair and black armor.

He meet the princess when he was young in a garden. Both remember each other.

He also own a small castle and an army (mostly his subordinate).

His sword is known as Eternal Beauty Sword (Sword of Eternal Beauty) which is one of the Demonic Swords that are known through the continent.

The only plot that don't match is they travel together while not knowing each other. The princess run away to Rain territory after the capital is captured. He know her but mistake her identity. She revealed right after that.

Image of main character and the princess
[image: Rain]

Comment: There's also a joke about Rain wearing the same clothes every day, and having a wardrobe containing multiple copies of the same black outfit. As such, this is very likely the correct answer.